# Cannot move "div" on handling "onclick" event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to click on a div and that div would be moved  and the div should follow my mouse.

What I have:

```
<div onclick="myFunction()" id="move"></div>


<script>
    function myFunction(){
        var div = document.getElementById('move');
        document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e){
        div.style.left=e.pageX+"px";
        div.style.top=e.pageY+"px";
    });}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another thing you need is you need to set `"Position:absolute"` for the style of div.

Answer (score 3):

Add this css:

```
div{
    position:absolute;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/mo4r0oks/)